# Is there a compiler for every Turing-complete programming language that compiles this programming language into any other programming language?

Tags: computer-science, computability, formal-languages

Recently I had to prove some theorems about programming languages. Originally I thought that I could assume that for every programming language there is a compiler that compiles that language into every other programming language and vice versa. Apparently this is wrong and I only have a partial proof of why this is so. So I was wondering if anyone has heard anything about this problem.
The exact formalisation is as follows:

Let $ P $ be the set of all computable functions.

A programming language is a computable function $ \psi $ in two arguments $ e, x $, where $ e $ is the Gödel number and $ x $ is the input. For $ \psi $, it must hold that for all $ f \in P $, there exists $ e \in \mathbb{N} $ such that $ \forall x: \psi(e, x) = f(x) $. We also define $ \psi_e := x \mapsto \psi(e, x) $. In other words, a computable function is a programming language if and only if every computable function in this programming language has a program.

We define an order $ \leq_R $ on programming languages as follows. For all programming languages $ \psi, \theta $, let

$$ \psi \leq_R \theta \Leftrightarrow \exists t \in P \forall e \in \mathbb{N} : \psi_e = \theta_{t(e)} $$

To prove: Let $\psi, \theta$ be programming languages. It follows that $\psi \leq_R \theta$

Comment: As a programmer, I completely misread your question! From the title, it looks like you are asking if a compiler _has been written_ for every Turing-complete programming language etc. (To which the answer is obviously no!)

Comment: This cannot be done.  A Friedberg numbering yields a counterexample.

Comment: Thank you, that's the example I was looking for. A programming language that has only one program per computable function can not be compiled because you cannot really program in it.
If anyone is interested, more details here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/116704/language-to-define-perfectly-a-programming-problem